# Zeros of $f$ in a disk

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms

If $f$ holomorphic in a domain $U$ and $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in U$ then every zero of $f$ is such that $f(q)=0$ and $\det(Df_{p})>0$. 
Using that I have to prove that if $f$ keeps that conditions and $D$ is a disk such that $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in \partial D$ then $\frac{1}{2i\pi }\int _{\partial D }\frac{df}{f}=$number of zeros of $f$ in $D$.

Now I have that $df=f'(z)dz$, so I have the expression $\frac{1}{2i\pi }\int _{\partial D }\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$.

But I don´t really know how that is useful, does any body can´t help?
thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem? Aside: The factor is $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$, not $\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think there was that mistake, but we can´t applied residue theorem or yes?

Comment: If you know the residue theorem, you can apply it. For that, you must find the singularities of $f'/f$ in $D$, and the residues there.

Comment: But the problem is to find the singularities because that expression should be the number of singularities.

Comment: I didn't mean to explicitly find the singularities. A characterisation of the singularities, $z_0$ is a singularity of $f'/f$ if and only if [...]. Its type is [...], and the residue is [...].

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you want to find the residues at all the singularities, you could just use the residue at infinity?